# Showing Movement Using R Plotly plot_geo

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I understand that when we use `plot_geo`, we can add markers/segments to the map.
Here is a sample code of the map that I generated:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

flights <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv')
flights$id <- seq_len(nrow(flights))

geo <- list(
  scope = 'world',
  projection = list(type = 'equirectangular'),  #equirectangular, natural earth, orthographic, kavrayskiy7, miller
  showland = TRUE,
  showcountries = TRUE,
  landcolor = toRGB("gray95"),
  countrycolor = toRGB("gray80")
)

p <- plot_geo(
  locationmode = 'country-names') %>%
  layout(geo = geo) %>%
  add_segments(
    data = flights, 
    x = ~start_lon, xend = ~end_lon,
    y = ~start_lat, yend = ~end_lat,
    alpha = 0.3,
    color = ~airport1,
    size = I(2.5),
    hoverinfo = "none"
  )
```

Is there any way to add an arrow instead of a line like `ggnetworkmap` or `ggmap` to show movement/direction?
Looking at the plot that I generated, it's hard to tell which way the arrow is moving. If this isn't possible, could someone suggest a different way to show direction?

Comment: `add_segments` adds a scatter trace where the points are connected but arrows are not supported. You could add an annotation which supports arrows but then you cannot toggle them in the legend.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters It seems like annotation would be hard to use since it won't take start/end lat & long. I've started to look at using leaflet instead, but it seems like I have to choose between an arc and a straight arrow, whereas I want both.

Comment: It looks like you are screwed. Perhaps make a feature request with the Plotly developers?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Haha I'm wanting to do too much with the maps. I did put in a request with the developers. Thanks for the comments.